# a field L containing $\mathbb{C}$ with $[L:\mathbb{C}]< \infty\ $ then $L=\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I want to show the following: 
"a field L containing  $\mathbb{C}$ with $[L:\mathbb{C}]< \infty\ $ then $L=\mathbb{C}$"

What I know:

1.$\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, so every polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ has at least one root in $\mathbb{C}$.

2.If $[L:\mathbb{C}]=\infty$, then there are infinity elements of L that are lin. indep on $\mathbb{C}$.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If $[L:\mathbf C]<\infty]$, every element of $L$ is algebraic over $\mathbf C$. As $\mathbf C$ is algebraically closed, this means every element of $L$ lies in $\mathbf C$, hence $L\subset\mathbf C$. As the opposite inclusion is true by hypothesis, we conclude that $L=\mathbf C$.

Comment: There are a few steps in between "algebraically closed" and "every element of $L$ lies in $\mathbb C$." It's not part of the usual definition of algebraically closed.

Comment: If the minimal polynomial of an element of $L$ already has all its roots in $\mathbf C$, which is contained in $L$, it is obvious for me.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\in L$. Since $L$ is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$, $a$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{C}$. The minimal polynomial $f(X)$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is irreducible.

What are the irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[X]$?